# How to read line that is 1000 or more lines above/under the current line?

Tags: bash, max, local

I need some help in reading line from bash.

I have graph in format x, y, z(x,y).(it is text file with 3 columns)
It is approx. 1000x1000 points big, so basically 1000000 columns.

I want to find local maximums, so i need to check the points 999,1000, 1001 before and after the current point, as well as one line before and after the current line. I don't want to keep track of 2k values(or i should?)

Any ideas?

Edit :
Looks like I am not clear.

there are 3 columns with numbers, like this:

```
0,0,0
0,1,0
0,2,0
1,0,0
1,1,1
1,2,0
2,0,0
2,1,0
2,2,0
```

so, the third column is dependent on first two in some way, and I want to find local  maximums for that column, in this case, i want to have result

```
1,1,1
```

Here, I have just one point that is maximum, but in principle,I am looking for local maximum, so I want all of them.

Edit 2:

All numbers in file are double precision.

I am terribly sorry for this mess, I am new to this forum, and i am new to bash-programming.

Comment: I think you have only asked a little part of what you are actually doing and it is hard to suggest a good answer without knowing some other things... What method are you using to find the local maxima and what are you doing with them? I mean, are you looking at the surrounding points by eye? Or are you passing them to another script? And what are you doing when you find them? Are you plotting them, if so, how?

Comment: Hopefully I made it clear now. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Thank you for placing your order for custom code on Stack Overflow. We're currently awaiting your pre-payment of US $1M (in small bills) so that we can begin solving your problems for you. --Or, you could post the code and error messages that you have, and explain what you think the problem with your code might be.

Comment: Two issues you haven't addressed. 1) Is a local maximum a value that is greater than all its neighbours, or one that is greater than OR EQUAL to all ita neighbours? 2) What happens at the edges of your grid - if a point is at the edge and there is no value above/below/left/right of it, can it still be aa maximum?

Comment: Almost clear -- **How do you define 'maximum'?** Is it the magnitude of the vector `| sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) |`, or is it simply the max of the dependent `z` (which is what it appears)?

Comment: Yes, yes, it is simply the max of the dependent z.It is strictly greater. I don't need full code, i need just to get values for those points that are 1000 lines away from my present line.
@CodeGnome, I am sorry you got such an impress, the thing is I don't have any code, I had actually no idea how do do it. The only think I could think of is to remember 2k values and work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED ANSWER**

Ok, I have read your new explanation, and I am still not sure I understand you but I think you have a 2-dimensional array of values and you are looking for any points that are larger than their immediate neighbours. Correct?

I would use something like this:

```
awk -F',' 'BEGIN {xmin=ymin=1000;xmax=ymax=-1000}

           {x=$1; y=$2
            if(x<xmin)xmin=x
            if(y<ymin)ymin=y
            if(x>xmax)xmax=x
            if(y>ymax)ymax=y
            grid[$1 SUBSEP $2]=$3
           }

     END   {
             for(x=xmin+1;x<=xmax-1;x++){
               for(y=ymin+1;y<=ymax-1;y++){
                  this=grid[x SUBSEP y];
                  if((this>grid[x-1 SUBSEP y-1]) &&
                     (this>grid[x-1 SUBSEP y  ]) &&
                     (this>grid[x-1 SUBSEP y+1]) &&
                     (this>grid[x-1 SUBSEP y  ]) &&
                     (this>grid[x+1 SUBSEP y  ]) &&
                     (this>grid[x+1 SUBSEP y-1]) &&
                     (this>grid[x+1 SUBSEP y  ]) &&
                     (this>grid[x+1 SUBSEP y+1]))
                     print x,y,this;
               }
            }
           }' file
```

The `-F` says your fields are separated by commas. At the start (in the `BEGIN{}` block) I initialiase the minimum and maximum values I have seen for `x`and `y` to some unlikely large/small values that will get overwritten when I read your data later in the next step.

Then, as I read each line, I extract the `x` and `y` values and check if they are greater or smaller than the largest `x` and `y` I have seen so far. That way I will know the limits of your grid - i.e. the minimum x value, the maximum x value, the minimum y value and the maximum y value. I also save each value I see in an array `grid[]` indexed by your `x` and `y` values.

At the end, after the whole file has been read, (in the `END{}` block) I loop through all the `x` and all the `y` values I have seen. For each `x` and `y`, I grab the `z` value from the `grid[]` array. I then check if this value is greater than all its 8 neighbours, and if it is, I print it out.

Note that this will not handle a maximum at the edge of your grid - you would have to change the `for` loop to `for(x=xmin;x<=xmax...` for that - as well as the `y` loop.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I am not sure I understand your question fully, so please explain (rather than downvote) what I have misunderstood if I have it wrong and I will correct my answer.

I think you want something like this:

```
awk -v r=11000 'BEGIN{
                 w[r-1]++; w[r]++; w[r+1]++;
                 w[r-1001]++;w[r-1000]++;w[r-999]++;
                 w[r+999]++;w[r+1000]++;w[r+1001]++
               } 
               NR in w{print $0}' file
```

Basically, you pass in the line number you are interested in, record 11000 in this example. Then, at the beginning, `awk` calculates all the line numbers you are going to want to see and stores them in the array `w[]` - think of this as the lines that are `wanted`. Then, as each record is read, it checks if that record is one you want and prints it if it is.

Output is something like this:

```
10,999,7
10,1000,7
11,1,7
11,999,7
11,1000,7
12,1,7
12,999,7
12,1000,7
13,1,7
```

You can make it a one-liner like this if your prefer:

```
awk -v r=11000 'BEGIN{w[r-1]++;w[r]++;w[r+1]++;w[r-1001]++;w[r-1000]++;w[r-999]++;w[r+999]++;w[r+1000]++;w[r+1001]++} NR in w{print $0}' file
```

Note that `awk` line numbers start at `1`, so you may need to fiddle the value of `r` accordingly to get the exact lines you actually mean.

Comment: I think you are on the right track from your explanation, but sadly, I don't know awk so good (that is why i asked) and i don't know what will it do exactly. I tried to clarify question in "edit", if it is not clear jet, I will try harder.. =)

Comment: I have had another attempt, please look again.

Comment: This should work for integer numbers only, am I right? If all the numbers are real (double precision) this does not work?

Comment: @LukaPetrović It should work fine for integers and doubles - it doesn't care.

Comment: and if it is not 1000x1000 but 1000000x1000000, then instead of
    BEGIN {xmin=ymin=1000;xmax=ymax=-1000}
i write 
    BEGIN {xmin=ymin=1000000;xmax=ymax=-1000000}
?

Comment: oh... actually, it does not matter, it concludes itself? Ok, thank you very much, today i learned something =)

Comment: Yes, it initially guesses an impossible (hopefully) size and corrects the guess as it reads in your data.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this file:

```
0,0,0
0,1,0
0,2,0
1,0,0
1,1,1
1,2,0
2,0,0
2,1,0
2,2,0
```

And if you want to get the 2 points around your match (1,1,1) you achieve it by writing:

```
$ cat mydata | grep -C2 -e '1,1,1'
0,2,0
1,0,0
1,1,1
1,2,0
2,0,0
```

Of course, you can change the number of line you want to get before/after your matching point:

```
-C<lines> # Above and After
-B<lines> # Before
-A<lines> # After
```

You can also try to match a specific value of y and z for any x:

```
cat t | grep -C2 -e '^[0-9]\+,\s*1,\s*3'
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear, you got me wrong. My bad. I edited it, hopefully it is understandable now.